# How to switch from Morden to Ropsten?

Tags: go-ethereum, clients, morden, ropsten, cli

I installed a v.0.8.7 client and tried **switching to Ropsten**, following [these](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/) instructions. Namely, I typed in:

```
dyn906-29:~ sam$ geth -- datadir /Users/sam/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata/ init /Users/sam/Library/Ethereum/testnet/testnet_genesis.json; geth -- datadir /Users/sam/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata/ --networkid 3 console
```

... synchronization started, with typical (i.e., after I let it run about 10 minutes) console output:

```
I1124 12:07:01.281067 eth/downloader/downloader.go:298] Synchronisation failed: block download canceled (requested)
I1124 12:07:23.178469 core/blockchain.go:975] imported 3 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 1.001425657s. #84205 [dc3d3bcd / c0b43021]
I1124 12:07:24.448356 core/blockchain.go:975] imported 3 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 2 txs in 8.001122ms. #84208 [e716f763 / 9cdfe671]
I1124 12:07:33.003664 core/blockchain.go:975] imported 2048 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 1897 txs in 4.743529105s. #86256 [2c5e179c / dbc9325e]
I1124 12:07:37.833884 core/blockchain.go:975] imported 2048 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 676 txs in 4.821595483s. #88304 [f9215a23 / 62150759]
```

What confuses me in this output it indicates I downloaded as many as 86256 blocks (see end of last line)... but I see [here](https://testnet.etherscan.io)  that there are only about 35000 blocks in the new testnet so far.

So I have the impression that I am synchronising with Morden..

**1. Am I currently synchronizing with Morden (instead of with Ropsten)?**

**2. How can I make sure my Client is synchronizing with Ropsten?**

Thanks.

EDIT: The GUI mentions a total of ca. 1,800 K blocks... so I am fairly positive my Client is synchronising with Morden. So how to move to Ropsten?

Comment: check the content of /Users/sam/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata/ is there the blockchain files? if not your command is wrong

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/switching-to-ropsten

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Geth 1.5.3](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.5.3) and later, it's 2 steps:

1. Run `geth --testnet removedb` to delete your blockchain database for the Morden network.
2. Run `geth --testnet`

---

ORIGINAL:

When you use `geth init`, the `datadir` should end with `/testnet`.  For example: `/Users/sam/Library/Ethereum/testnet`

When you use other commands like `geth console`, the `datadir` should be the parent directory, in this example: `/Users/sam/Library/Ethereum`

Yes, it is confusing.  But when Geth 1.5.3 is released, `geth --testnet` will simplify it and you don't need to bother with `geth init`.

It is helpful to start with a clean `datadir` (you may need to manually create the `/testnet` subdirectory), but make sure that you back up your existing `datadir`: be careful to make sure you do not lose any `keystore`.

Comment: I may need to double-check this but posting for now in case it helps.  EDIT: I won't check the original post since Geth 1.5.3 has now been released.

Comment: The `geth --testnet removedb` part is the most useful part of your answer, maybe you should highlight it a bit more. It's actually more of an answer than "just run `geth --testnet`"

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Thanks for the suggestion! I improved the answer (which came from a similar question and your comment was very helpful).

Answer (score 3):

In your second call there is a space between `--` and `datadir`, so probably you are running geth with the wrong data directory and therefore you are using the wrong genesis block. Try running

```
geth --datadir /Users/sam/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata/ --networkid 3 console
```

instead of

```
geth -- datadir /Users/sam/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata/ --networkid 3 console
```

Comment: you are right, thank you so much. Part of the problem remains, in that after I entered these command, Ethereum wallet appears to still be synchronising with Morden (since it says that it needs to download 1800K blocks). Any idea on how to go about this?