# Switching to Ropsten on windows

Tags: testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm using geth on a linux VM, and Ethereum Wallet on my Windows. I had no problem at all switching to Ropsten on linux, but my Wallet refuses to change.

I used `geth --datadir /path/to/testnet/data init genesis.json; geth --datadir /path/to/testnet/data --networkid 3 console`, it managed to sync but when I run `geth --testnet console` it's back on Morden, same with the wallet.

As I wanted to change the Wallet, I used the version of geth in `Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked`, but I don't know if it's the right one. I'm also not sure what `/path/to/testnet/data` is, I used `...\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\`

---

I used [this blog post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/), [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10261/from-morden-to-ropsten) worked on linux but not windows, and [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/switching-to-ropsten) is an unrelated problem of absolute and relative paths.

---

*Update* : Honestly I'm speechless. The wallet seemed to work (synced to ~60k blocks) even though I don't think I did anything useful, and now it's trying to download the 1,800k blocks of the old blockchain back. Why.

*Update2* : I managed to get work done by restarting my wallet everytime it went crazy and back to the 1.800k blocks, and I realized my geth console (not even on the same machine) went crazy at the same time, also setting top block to 1.800k. I don't know if it's syncing on Morden or if it's just a bug and it still uses Ropsten, I can't tell. It seems to stay at 69k.

*Update3* : It doesn't work anymore to close and restart the wallet. Now it looks for peers and downloads the 1,800k Morden blockchain. If I start geth alone, (with no parameters other it does show `networkid=3` but can't find the blockchain data.

*Update4* : I found a temporary fix. I can alway rerun the whole switching (`get --datadir ... --networkid 3 console`), but I lose all my wallet data (contracts and have to reload the blockchain. The "fix" I found is after reseting and starting Eth Wallet, I actually run `geth --testnet console` with a command prompt in the background, and it seems to keep the blockchain correctly synced, avoiding the Wallet to fall back to syncing Morden (which is weird because I couldn't run geth and the Wallet at the same time before). And when it does, just run `exit`and `geth --testnet console` again. I don't know what happens after you reboot your pc but at least I can work 2+ hours in a row without losing my data. I'm starting to think it's not going to go away until the next version of Mist...

Comment: Same here, there is a suspicious block in the log when geth magically switches chains: ########## BAD BLOCK ######### Chain config: {ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10} Number: 1 Hash: 0xad47413137a753b2061ad9b484bf7b0fc061f654b951b562218e9f66505be6ce Error: Block's parent unknown 0cd786a2425d16f152c658316c423e6ce1181e15c3295826d7c9904cba9ce303 ############################## Is it at all possible that some peers (try to) mine blocks belonging to morden on top of ropsten? That same hash keeps coming back at new block numbers and there is also stu

Comment: You can format your answers in comments to, for example write `########## BAD BLOCK #########` instead of ########## BAD BLOCK #########.  You can do that using grave accents : `