# How to run a testnet json rpc server?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, testnets

I recently tried getting back into developing on Ethereum and it seems that everything about my setup has changed in the last half a year. I used to just be able to download a wallet from https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases , and be able to connect to the public testnet easily. Now even the installation guide for geth tells me [how to run a private testnet](https://www.ethereum.org/cli#connecting-to-a-private-test-net), but not how to connect to the public one...

So, I got my Windows geth from https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ . I tried running `geth.exe --testnet --rpc --rpcapi "personal"`, but it doesn't appear to be synching with anything like it used to.

How can I connect geth to a public testnet, synch with it, get some ether to play around with and be able to connect to everything through a json rpc connection?

Comment: This is just a bad timing I think. The public testnet `morden` with id `2` was just reset and `ropsten` with id `3` introduced. Clients may not be ready, yet, to support them native, however, you can migrate manually, [see for example this thread](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10261/87), and [for mist](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10205/87), and [one more for windows](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10389/87).

Comment: Be careful using RPC with the `personal` API: it can allow people to brute-force your accounts. IPC is better in most cases

Comment: @TjadenHess Can you elaborate on this? As in, how would using RPC with the personal API allow people to brute force your accounts, assuming you were running the testnet?